# AngularJS, como mudar a tags colchetes ({{ e }}) para qualquer outro carácter de sua escolha?

Tags: angularjs

No [**AngularJS**](https://angularjs.org/) por padrão vem as tags colchetes (`{{` e `}}`) para manipulação, queria alterar para `%%` e `%%`, como devo proceder ?

Exemplo:

```
{{name}}
```

*para*

```
%%name%%
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para trocar, precisa configurar na sua aplicação dessa forma: no [$interpolateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24interpolateProvider), coloque a `startSymbol` e `endSymbol` setando para `%%`

```js
var App = angular.module('App',[]);

App.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('%%');
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%%');
});
```

Exemplo:

*Angular:*

```js
var App = angular.module('App',[]);

App.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('%%');
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%%');
});

function PeopleListCtrl($scope){
    $scope.peoples = [
        {'id': 1, 'name': 'Nome 1'}, 
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'Nome 2'}
    ];     
};
```

*Html Completo com AngularJS:*

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.10/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>    
    <div ng-controller="PeopleListCtrl">
        <br />
        <p>Quantidade: %%peoples.length%%</p>
        <br />
        <ol>
            <li ng-repeat="p in peoples">%%p.id%% - %%p.name%%</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var App = angular.module('App',[]);
    App.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
          $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('%%');
          $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%%');
    });

    function PeopleListCtrl($scope){
        $scope.peoples = [
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'Nome 1'}, 
            {'id': 2, 'name': 'Nome 2'}
        ];     
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Resultado: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruxohpotter/kMPxQ/47/)

*Referências:*

- [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)
- [$interpolateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24interpolateProvider)
- [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)